# how to solve Parsing expression Lexer error yq

Tags: shell, yaml, sh, yq

I am using `yq` for YAML processor. I got this error:

Error: Parsing expression: Lexer error: could not match text starting at 1:8 failing at 1:10. unmatched text: "to"

Following is the code:

```
 function query() {
  cat "$SOURCE" | yq eval "$@" -
 }

 function get_env_for_url() {
  local URL="$1"

  local ENV_URL=$(query ".env | to_entries | .[] | select( .value.url == \"$URL\") | .key")

  echo $ENV_URL
}
```

sample YAML file:

```
env:
  app:
    url: abc.com
  dev:
    url: dev.com
  data:
    url: data.com
```

How to solve Parsing expression: Lexer error?

Comment: This is solved by using the latest yq version 4.14.1

Comment: I strongly advise against generating a yq program from the shell. It's too easy to introduce [code injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_injection) bugs using that approach. Can't you provide `$URL` via an argument or the environment? (I'm not familiar with `yq`, but it's inspired by `jq` which provides the means to do both.)

Comment: ...there are two separate programs named `yq` -- one is a wrapper around jq, one is completely its own program with independent syntax. A question needs to specify which one is in use to be usefully answered.

Comment: Re "*Can't you provide $URL via an argument or the environment?*", yeah, you can use `URL="$URL" query '... | select( .value.url = env(URL) ) | ...'`

Comment: That said, there's no reason to write this particular YAML file using YAML-only syntax. You could write it with JSON syntax -- it would still be valid YAML (YAML is a superset of JSON -- all JSON is also valid YAML), but then you could edit it with `jq` and not need YAML-specific tools.

Comment: Thank you for this fruitful suggestion Instead of using YAML I'll go with JSON(jq).